# CRM 2013 - New Button visible even though user does not have Create rights

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

We've just upgraded to 2013 and I noticed that the Contacts View New Button is available even though the user does not have Create rights on the Security Role.

[image]

Anyone else experience this sort of behaviour? Should I add a DisplayRule to my ribbonXML to hide it based on role (Don't know if this is supported..) or am I missing something on my Role?

Answer (score 1):

Do the default Team for the Business Unit that the user is in, or a Team that this user belongs to, have their own Security Role? If so, I would check the Security Roles assigned to default Team for the Business Unit and any other additional Teams that the user belongs to and see if they have the Team has a 'Create' privilege.

If this is the case, the user would be inheriting the Create privilege from their Team.